# Objects and references in java - explain the answer

Tags: java, reference

I am confused as I am new to java, how many objects and references are created in the following piece of code?

```
public class Test {

Test obj1,obj2,obj3;

    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        new Test();
        obj2=obj3=new Test();
    }
}
```

Please explain the answer:

> 2 objects, 3 references

Comment: I only count two objects, two references. Shouldn't the first line of `main` read as `obj1=new Test();` for that to happen? Or is `String[] ar` also under consideration?

Comment: @hexafraction: null reference, I presume.

Comment: `new Test()` calls a constructor which creates a new object, you call it twice. References are: `obj1`, `obj2` and `obj3`.

Comment: There are actually 4 references. `String ar[]` is an object reference too. ; )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code snippet create two objects of type `Test`, one everywhere `new Test();` is written.

There are also 3 references (variables)<sup>1</sup> in here: `obj1,obj2,obj3`.

At the end, you have :

- 1 object unreachable
- One object referenced by `obj2,obj3`,
- `obj1` referring to `null`.

Also note, you seem to have forgotten to declare the variables as `static` - otherwise the code won't compile. ("Cannot make static reference to a non static field") - since `main()` is static - it can only access *class variables* (which have the `static` modifier attached to them)

```
public class Test {

    static Test obj1,obj2,obj3; //3 references/variables
  //  ^
  //added static keyword


    public static void main(String ar[]) {  
        new Test(); //1 object
        obj2=obj3=new Test(); //second object created
    //  ^obj2,obj3 both are referring the 2nd object now
    }
}
```

---

(1) To `Test` objects.